# Mail going to spam asp.net

Tags: .net, email, spam

I am trying to send email with following code snippet.

```
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
        mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("cs@abc.com");
        mailMsg.Subject = "Test";
        mailMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");


        mailMsg.To.Add("abc.test@gmail.com");



        // Set the body of the mail message
        var BodyText = "<html><body>Hi..</body></html>";


        System.Net.Mail.AlternateView plainView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BodyText, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty), null, "text/plain");
        System.Net.Mail.AlternateView htmlView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(BodyText, null, "text/html");
        mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        // Smtp configuration
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "mail.shopmanza.com";
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("cs@abc.com", "Cs@abc");
        smtp.Send(mailMsg);
```

My mail goes to spam folder instead of inbox. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your mail client thinks it's a spam for a motive, change spam filtering rules  or the mail body/from. IMHO it have nothing to do with your code *per si*

Comment: Hi Jean,Thanks for your reply. I am sending this mail to lots of my website customers who may use gmail. How can i make sure that this mail is not going to their spam folder?

Comment: Can you try a plain text email without links from a real addres? Before anything read gmail documentantion: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Mail going to spam section due various reason.
i) Check your host name it should be your domain name instead of localhost
ii) sending from test,support email this should be valid email id of your domain.
iii) Sending single image in content.

You can avoid mail goes to spam by installing DKIM
http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/08/installing-opendkim-rpm-via-yum-with-postfix-or-sendmail-for-rhel-centos-fedora/